Is there an elegant way to subclass a Python list which keeps its subclass when adding and slicing, etc
I want to extend the functionality of a standard list, subclassing seems like the obvious way. Actually, I'm using this to store a mathematical expression in Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) for a genetic programming project.
class RPN(list):
    def evaluate(self, vars):
        # evaluate the RPN expression
        pass

    def to_infix(self):
        # convert to infix form
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def from_infix(expr):
        # create new RPN object from infix expression sting
        pass

This works fine, I can create an RPN object like RPN([5, 6, operator.add, 7, 8, operator.add, operator.mult]), and it works as intended.
My problem is that I want do list-like operations to these RPN objects, such as append, add together, slice, etc. but when I do this they revert back to plain old lists (apart from append - that's ok).
So, for example:
rpn1 = RPN([5, 6, operator.add])
rpn2 = RPN([7, 8, operator.add])
rpn3 = rpn1 + rpn2
# type(rpn3) == list
rpn4 = rpn1[0:1]
# type(rpn4) == list

I can understand why, because a new object gets created, and it creates it as a list. I suppose I can change this behaviour, but then I would have to provide new implementations for __add__, slicing methods, etc. And all of a sudden, I'm writing a lot more code than I intended. Alternatively, I can remake everything as an RPN object each time, e.g. rpn3 = RPN(rpn1 + rpn2), but this also seems clunky.
Is there a better way?
Note, this question was marked as a duplicate of How to use list comprehension in list derived class. The tagged post was asking about how to use list comprehensions inside a derived list class (and in an odd way, by reassigning self variable inside __init__ function), I'm asking about something completely different. It just so happens, that both these are solved by using collections.UserList, but the questions themselves are not duplicates IMHO.

Subclass collections.UserList, instead - all of its methods generate objects of the same class.

That works! Brilliant. I knew there was a better way. Feel free to post as answer and I can accept that, or I can add as answer and give you the kudos.

The post was closed as a duplicate, I've added a note about why I think this is not a duplicate (although the answer to use collections.UserList is the same). Same answer doesn't mean same question. If it get's reopened, I merely want to add the use of collections.UserList as provided by @jasonharper as an answer and accept it.

please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

RPN should use composition, not inheritance. An arbitrary slice of an RPN expression is not necessarily a valid RPN expression itself, so there's little reason to "inherit" list.__getitem__ to create them.

I'm posting this, but @jasonharper  provided the answer. The solution to my problem was to subclass collections.UserList rather than list. All of its methods generate objects of the same class. Works perfectly.

Just use plain lists:
rpn1 = [5, 6, operator.add]
rpn2 = [7, 8, operator.add]

and define your operations as functions like:
def evaluate(vars):
    # evaluate the RPN expression
    pass

def to_infix(vars):
    # convert to infix form
    pass

def from_infix(expr):
    # create new RPN object from infix expression sting
    pass

Now you are able to use all list operations along with the new ones you have defined.

I did this originally, but thought subclassing was more OOP. But actually, I like the simplicity of this solution - and I ended up using it. However, for the answer to my question, I'm going for the collections.UserList because that does seem the best way to subclass a list.
